# How do I override the power cycling when the battery gets below 5%?

Tags: battery, kindle-fire, power-management

I know that I probably shouldn't let the battery run so low on my Kindle Fire, but occasionally I have let it dip below 5%.  Once this happens, the device no longer let's me trickle charge, and it powers itself down, even while plugged in.

Is there a way to override this setting?  Sometimes I want to finish something up before letting it rest and charge up completely.  To what extent does it damage the battery to run it so low?

Comment: I believe the Kindle Fie is designed to shutdown when the battery charge is low to protect the battery cells from being damaged (Lithium Ion batteries self-discharge). Not a good idea to let them run too low (often).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible. The exact explanation for this actually comes from Android. Buried deep within the Android source code is this little gem:

[BatteryService.java:239](http://androidxref.com/source/xref/frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/BatteryService.java#239)

```
private void shutdownIfNoPowerLocked() {
    if (mBatteryLevel == 0 && !isPoweredLocked(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_ANY)) {
        [...]
```

This basically forces the system to shutdown if the battery level reaches 0%. The `isPoweredLocked` function determines whether any of the following are true:

- The battery status is unknown
- The device is connected to AC
- The device is connected via a USB cable
- The device is within range of a wireless charger

It should also be noted (as Jason mentioned in [his comment](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-do-i-override-the-power-cycling-when-the-battery-gets-below-5#comment690_588)) that lithium-ion batteries typically power off when they reach a predetermined low voltage to prevent further discharge and consequent damage.

Comment: No problem - I ran into a similar problem when the battery gauge on one of my Android phone went berserk and it wouldn't stay powered on even with a full battery.